# What is this strange folder that is always accumulating files?

Tags: windows-xp

I found this folder the other day when I got a "drive full" notice. It was full of files randomly named like the folder itself (see pic below). I deleted all I could, but there was 1 file that was being used, and that remains and is growing. What's the best way to go about identifying what process/program is responsible?

[image]

Comment: Use sysinternals process monitor to see what program is accessing that file. In the mean time set it to read only to stop it from growing.

Comment: Boot into safe mode and see if the growth stops, if it does, suspect your AV software is causing it.

Comment: I smell a virus.

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Comment: @ChrisF - Good idea. Done.

Comment: No Virus, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the SysInternals task manager program: [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

In the Process Explorer interface there is a search command that you can use to search for this file path. Process Explorer will then show you the executable(s) working in this directory and creating these files.

Then run an internet search for the name of the process(es) working in this directory to determine whether they are malware or not.

Comment: When I used Process Explorer, I found it wasn't being used anymore. I was able to delete without any problem. The only thing I had done prior that might relate are several reboots and making it "read-only" as Kyle suggested. Thanks for your answer. If it happens again I know where to start.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

`-k -q` are parameters, so I suspect you have a virus and this file are the results of executing the name.

Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what process accesses the file.

Answer (score 1):

It happened again. I didn't actually need SysInternals. I just opened Task Manager, found what was using the most memory (this thing was churning 200MB files out every sec) and it was obvious. Turns out the culprit was [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/index.php) running an erase task on unused disk space. The option to delete cluster tips was checked--not sure if that's important. No virus though. Here's an image of exactly what it does:

[image]

Comment: I suppose that's one say to wipe free space.